# AWS JWT authorizer not supporting google issuer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-jwt-authorizer, aws-http-api

- the issuer in the tokens from google is: "accounts.google.com"
- but the jwt-authorizer config requires an issuer url with "https://" in front

That means the google tokens never be accepted by the authorizer since the token iss claim is missing: https

Any one solved this?

Comment: API Gateway here - We'll fix this ASAP. It is a strange behavior that Google doesn't vend a token with the scheme included in the URI. I'll post an answer here when this is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using some of the legacy oauth flow to authorize your app. you may get a token with the issuer above, make sure to use the OIDC config:

https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Then the issuer in the id-token should match the format required by AWS JWT-Authorizer (and specified in the OIDC [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) ).